# Onscroll event on the body wont trigger

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

My onscroll in my body tag dosn't trigger my javascript function.
I don't know why but the scroll() wont trigger. I have the newest version of chrome, but it still dosn't work

```js
function scroll() {



  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;

  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "scrolled " + scrollTop + " pixels";











}
```

```css
p {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>



<body onscroll="scroll()">

  <p id="text"></p>



<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

</body>
```

Comment: Chrome 44.0 here: your snippet works.

Comment: Working as well in FireFox 40.0.3

Comment: ohhh It works for me aswell... Well it still dosn't work on my real file. Which is basicly the same

Comment: `dosn't work on my real file`. People can fix your issue only if you help them to reproduce your issue

Comment: Haha sorry to bother all of you. I accidently forgot to save the html file.